# I want to fire off sequential queries to mysql using node.js but only the last one is fired off

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

```
connection.query(listprofiles,function(error,profilesReturned){
     console.log(profilesReturned.length)
     for (var i=0;i<profilesReturned.length;i++){
          console.log(profilesReturned[i].column)
          var query2='SELECT IF(COUNT(*) >0, TRUE,FALSE)
                      as response FROM table where 
                      column1='+connection.escape(staticvalue)+'AND
                      r_circleowner_id='+connection.escape(
                      profilesReturned[i].column);
          console.log(i+':'+query2);
          connection.query(query2,function(error,result){           
                        console.log(result)
          })
```

In the above code, I first run a query called 'listprofiles' which returns a set of responses. For every individual response I get from the query, I want to pass it on to query2. I attempted a for loop but only the last query is fired of to mysql. The last query is generated from the last element of profilesReturned set.

How do I ensure that separate queries containing separate values from profilesReturned are fired off sequentially or asynchronously?

Comment: There should be no problem with the code you've presented. The only time loops and asynchronous function calls don't mix is when you're referencing a variable that changes in the loop (e.g. counter variable), inside the asynchronous callback.

Comment: What `mysql` module do you use? Is the output of `console.log(i+':'+query2);` shown for every query you want to create or only for the first one?

Comment: @t.niese I used the mysql module listed at https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Comment: @t.niese `console.log(i+':'+query2)` prints every query

Comment: And you are sure `console.log(result);` is only called once?  could you replace it with `if( error ) { console.log(error); } else { console.log(result); }` to see if there was an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connection.query() is async. You need to use something that can control the loop such as async.each() for parallel or async.eachSeries() for series:

```
var async = require('async');
var results = [];

connection.query(listprofiles,function(error,profilesReturned){
  console.log(profilesReturned.length)
  async.each(profilesReturned, function(item, callback) {
      console.log(item.column)
      var query2='SELECT IF(COUNT(*) >0, TRUE,FALSE)
                  as response FROM table where 
                  column1='+connection.escape(staticvalue)+'AND
                  r_circleowner_id='+connection.escape(
                  item.column);
      connection.query(query2,function(err,result){ 
        if (!err) {          
          console.log(result);
          results.push(result);
        }
        callback();
      });
}, function(err) {
  console.log("all done");
  console.log(results.length);
});
```

Comment: With some more modifications, I was able to achieve what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using promises - upon success of query one, you resolve the promise and execute query two, and so on.

Example with [node-promise](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-promise)

```
var Promise = require("promise").Promise;
var promise = new Promise();
asyncOperation(function(){
  Promise.resolve("succesful result");
});

promise.then(function(result){
   ... when the action is complete this is executed ...
},
function(error){
    ... executed when the promise fails
});
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Deferred objects are certainly the best practice for looping async logic and will solve his reference issue.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but whilst you outline an answer, it is a bit vague on the details and could be more precisely tailored to the question. I'm not going to comment on which answer is better technically, but the one by Ben above more specifically targets the actual question

Comment: Give a man a fish/Teach a man to fish. OP's pointed in the right direction now.

Comment: You need to teach him how to adapt to local conditions, not just the general principle of fishing ;o)